How to change the source GitHub repository for a deployed project on Google Cloud Run?
I have an app on Google Cloud Run that deploys changes when I push changes to the main branch of my GitHub repo. The first time the app was deployed on Google Cloud Run, I selected my GitHub repo in the settings.
I have now transferred my GitHub repo to an organization so the source GitHub has changed. When I push the changes to main, I do not see those changes on the deployed app. How do I tell Google Cloud Run the new source/URL of GitHub repo? I can't find that setting.
After clicking EDIT CONTINUOUS DEPLOYMENT, I see this setting on the page:

Is this where I can select the GitHub repo that was transferred to an organization?

For editing the Repository,Access the repository

Select edits  and modify the repository. For detailed instructions on modifying the repository, refer to this document.
